# Как вставить подзапрос во второй аргумент функции join orm codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm

Я пытался убрать двойные кавычки, но в функции join они не убираются.

```
$this->db->select('a.id')->from('abit.v_anketa a')
->join('abit.statement_statuses ss', '(SELECT  statement_status_id FROM  abit.anketa_statuses  
        WHERE anketa_id = a.id ORDER BY date_time_created DESC LIMIT 1) = ss.id', 'left');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получилось сделать это, но вышло не совсем красиво. Вот мое решение:

```
$this->db->select('a.id')->from('abit.v_anketa a LEFT JOIN abit.statement_statuses ss ON (SELECT  statement_status_id FROM  abit.anketa_statuses  
                    WHERE anketa_id = a.id ORDER BY date_time_created DESC LIMIT 1) = ss.id')
```